# Meaning of 'an old hat'

Tags: meaning

I found the phrase “old hat” in the following sentence of The New York Times’ article (April 20) titled, “[The Tech-Savvy Traveler](http://travel.nytimes.com/2012/04/22/travel/the-tech-savvy-traveler.html).”

> AT 28 years old, Soraya Darabi is *an old hat* at staying on the cutting
>   edge of social media. Her first job out of college was in the
>   communications department for Condé Nast Digital for products like
>   epicurious.com. At 23, she became the manager of digital partnerships
>   and social media at The New York Times and went on to help found
>   Foodspotting (foodspotting.com), a Web site and digital application
>   that aggregates real-time dining advice.

What did the journalist mean when she wrote "an old hat"?

Comment: Have you looked this up anywhere? What did you find?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/old_hat

Comment: @Hugo, et al: Yes, _old hat_ is general reference, but the issue here is that the writer made a mistake. See the answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What may be confusing in this passage is that the phrase *old hat* is usually used to describe objects or activities with which one is very familiar. The correct way for this author to use the phrase would have been to write:

> Staying on the cutting edge of social media is old hat for 28 year-old Soraya Darabi.

According to the blog [Publisher's Round-up](http://wmjasco.blogspot.com/2012/04/are-you-old-hat.html), the author made a mistake in this passage and should have used the phrase *old hand*:

> old hand |oʊld hønd|
>
> *noun*
> a person with a lot of experience in something : *he was an old hand at red-tape cutting.*

(As an added twist, [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/old-hat.html), claims the saying *old hat* may have originally referred to a woman's private parts. I imagine this would have made the above mistake less forgivable to an earlier audience.)

Comment: Surely you have researched your answer better than me; however, the first meaning of the definitions in Wikipedia is "Something ... in which one is experienced or skilled". Not so very different from the meaning you posted, I'd say.

Comment: @Paola: No, I agree. However, the key here is that the author confused two idioms and so confused readers.

Comment: Fair enough, then. Not being a native speaker, I did not realize that something in the wording was bizarre, although I knew the expression "to be an old hand". Still, I think that your comment to my post has provoked the downvote it got...

Comment: @Paola: That was me. I'll reverse it if you edit out the admonition.

Comment: Done, but I still think he should have checked a bit more.

Comment: @Paola -- unless Callithumpian is snooping around your backyard, you should have written "you have researched your answer better than *I*."

Comment: @Malvolio. Should I? I thought that the correct way of saying it was "...than I did" or else "... than me", and that the first option was a bit stiff. Could you explain it to me? (By the way, how can you use italics or bold print in commentaries?)

Comment: @Malvolio. I've been thinking about the first part of your above comment and, although I can understand the literal meaning of the sentence, what do you mean by " X is snooping around your backyard"? I haven't found it anywhere as a full expression.

Comment: @Paola -- Your sentence "you have researched your answer better than me" is an elision of "you have researched your answer better than *you researched me*" (when you meant the elision of "you have researched your answer better than *I researched my answer*" -- in English you don't change the case of any pronouns when you elide).  I was trying to come up with a vivid reification of Callithumpian researching you.  I thought suggesting she was digging in your trash a bit *too* vivid and anything closer would sound actually threatening.

Comment: @Malvolio. Thank you for the explanation. The grammar books which I've been using weren't as crystal clear as your words. And thank you for the clarification of the expression; in a sense it's true  I could almost feel Callithumpian reproachfully staring at me and my comments :-)

Comment: In his book "the Etymologicon" Mark Forsyth advises that the phrase "old hat" is used as slang for a woman's private parts because it's often felt.

Answer (score 15):

That's an error on the part of the writer.  She's conflating two expressions.

One is *old hat*, a phrasal adjective referring to "something widely or long practiced, known, or accepted; something conventional". So, "90s singer Madonna is old-hat."  (NB: *not* "Madonna is *an* old-hat.")

The other is *an old hand*, "a person who is experienced at a certain activity". Here, a "hand" is a sailor, as in "all hands on deck".

*The New York Times* used to be a well-edited newspaper; those Times are gone forever, I fear.

**EDIT**:
Callithumpian points out that this particular error has already been the subject of the [online thrashing](http://wmjasco.blogspot.com/2012/04/are-you-old-hat.html) it deserves.

Comment: +1 for adding the last line about NYT. I think it's no more a newspaper but a mouthpiece of anti-free market ideologues.

Comment: @Cameron -- and here I was, expecting +1 for the [Don Henley reference](http://www.google.com/search?q=don+henley+those+times+are+gone+forever).  But lesson learned: the key to upvotes is gratuitous attacks on the MSM.

Comment: +1 for great answer, but I accepted @Callithumpian 's answer because he was the first to point out the journalist error.

Comment: @Carlo: Actually, I believe Malvolio beat me to writer's error part. I just found corroboration of it at another site. If you'd like to switch your acceptance, I'm fine with that.

Comment: Carlo -- I was first on this thread but @Callithumpian found the posting on another blog from a *week* earlier discussing the error, which is cool.

Answer (score 1):

I've found explanations for "***old hat***" in OALD, in TheFreeDictionary, but the best explanation is [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/old_hat) in Wikipedia.

Comment: @Callithumpian. Sorry if I gave the wrong impression, I didn't mean to scold (that is, to speak angrily to somebody, especially a child, because they have done something wrong, as OALD defines it) and I hope Carlo will not be put off by my remark. Sometimes I'm under the impression that his interventions, either questions or answers, are a bit too rushed and that they would profit from a more careful approach.

Comment: @Kris, a better way to answer would be to include the relevant part of the linked answer in the answer here, as the link may change (and in the case of Wikipedia, almost certainly the content will change).

Comment: @OldPro. I'll try to do it in the future. For the time being, you can refer to the exchange of comments between Callithumpian and me in the post above mine.

Comment: @Old Pro Thank you, but we are old hats around here.

Comment: @Paola - +1, although my question had the purpose to show the journalist usage of 'old hat', rather than to know its meaning.